# MS Teams Calendar Deep Links: How to remove Microsoft Teams meeting section

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We use deep links to generate the calendar appointments in MS Teams.
It works great, hoewer it inserts the Microsoft Teams Join Meeting section. Are there any ways to remove it? 
We use the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-the-scheduling-dialog

Link example: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meeting/new?subject=test%20subject&attendees=joe@contoso.com,bob@contoso.com&startTime=10%2F24%2F2018%2010%3A30%3A00&endTime=10%2F24%2F2018%2010%3A30%3A00&content=test%3Acontent

Section that should be removed:
[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any way to remove that section. It is by design.

Comment: How did you open outlook invitation window? I am also using the same deeplink, for me it is opening teams window.

Answer (score 1):

For more visibility, adding answer from the comment section:

I don't think there is any way to remove that section. It is by design.